# Centering menu buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit lost in the weeds trying to customize a jekyll theme. My repository is capecchi.github.io and I'm trying to get some menu icons centered. I have looked into how to do this and have successfully gotten the blog/project buttons centered, but for some reason my social buttons below are slightly off-center to the right. The only added class that I can see (in header.html) is the "navigation--social" class (defined in /css/uno.css), and I can't find where in this class it might define a left margin or anything. I'm new to web development and have been poking at this for quite some time (hence the "TESTING" button I added). I'm just stuck finding where this offset is coming from and would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: I will also add that I find 7 instances of ".navigation--social" in the file /css/uno.css and no where else. However, changing these parameters seems to have no effect on the layout. For example, lines 1391-1392 of uno.css has the following:

.navigation--social {
 margin-left: 1.5em; }

This seems to me a likely place to remove an unwanted lefthand margin. But changing this seems to have no effect. Stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a margin-left of 1.5em on `.navigation--social` (uno.css line 1391).

Actually, removing this margin centers the buttons quite good but not perfectly, because there is another margin-right on `.navigation__item` (uno.css line 1376). You should either put an equal amount of margin-left or remove the margin-right to get perfectly centered buttons.

I found this out by using the inspector of Firefox. Most browsers come with this feature, you can open it up by right-clicking the page and selecting "Inspect Element" from the context menu.

[Screenshot of the inspector window showing the margins and the offending styles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZeGa.jpg)

Comment: Thank you! This was soooo helpful- not only did I fix the problem, but now I know how to be much more effective at tracking down issues in the future! I feel like you taught me how to fish today.